# Shouldn't the derivative not exist

Tags: calculus

[derrivative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U3k5.png)Professor has shown us this calculations but does the function have a partial derrivative with respect to x in the point (0,0)? the original function is $$u(x,y)=\frac{(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: The "computation" you have posted is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The partial derivative with respect to $x$ is obtained by holding $y$ constant and differentiating with respect to $x$.  Notice that $u(x,0)=x$ so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1$ at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

First, my guess is that $u(0,0)$ is defined to be zero and not via the rule for $u(x,y)$ that you give above. Then, use the limit definition of the derivative so that

\begin{equation*} \frac{u(h,0)-u(0,0)}{h}=\frac{\frac{h^{3}}{h^{2}}-0}{h}=\frac{h^{3}}{h^{3}}=1\end{equation*}

so taking $h\to 0$ gives $u_{x}(0,0)=1$.